# Minimal English: Lack Of Clarity And Redundancy

Tags: english, lexicography

In terms of semantic useful words, Minimal English lists:

**Foods:**

corn (yams, etc.)

flour

meat

rice

salt

sugar

sweet

wheat

**Technology And Transport:**

bicycle

boat

car

engine

phone

pipe

plane

radio

road

telephone

television

train

wheel

wire

**Q1:** I don't understand the relationship between corn and yams. If the relationship is just about being vegetables and/or fruits, why not list that first, then include examples in parentheses?

**Ex.:**

fruits/vegetables (corn, yams, etc.)

**Q2:** Why does it list both "phone" and "telephone"? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: What is your source for a list of "Minimal English" words? Mine includes neither.

Comment: @user6726 https://books.google.com/books?id=cbM4DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false
p. 17.

Comment: The Natural Semantic Metalanguage people are getting into Basic English territory? That... is more of a surprise than it should be....

Comment: Ok, so that is a proposed extension, not words actually on the list.

Comment: @user6726 There are semantic primes, semantic molecules (univeral but non-prime words), and semantic useful words (non-universal words that might still simplify a particular NSM). These are just some of the latter-most. As Nick Nicholas noted in his answer, they're apparently just not well-thought out or edited at this point.

Comment: @user6726 Oh ya, and of course, there are semantic functors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://books.google.com.au/books?id=cbM4DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=phone&f=false

I'm flabbergasted that the [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage) people have actually gone there, and tried to reinvent [Basic English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English) as [Minimal English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage#Minimal_English). I'm not surprised [Cliff Goddard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Goddard) is behind the effort; he's always been an evangelist for NSM.

In context, the list of words that derives from is a list of candidates for inclusion in the Minimal English vocabulary, rather than the definitive list of semantic primes that precedes it; and you can tell: it clearly has not been rigorously defined or cleaned up. Goddard admits that the list is a grabbag. I think the inclusion of *telephone* and *phone* is just poor editing.

As for corn/yams, the list in context is: *meat, rice, wheat, corn, (yams etc.)*; I surmise the actual intent is "any number of starchy staples, which could be expanded by region" (so "yams etc." are an extension of the set "rice, wheat, corn"). Again, this is a thrown-together list of candidate words, so they don't seem to have felt the need to pare it down.

Comment: Ogden's "Basic English" isn't the only one of its kind... Do Godard et al actually claim to be reinventing it specifically?

Comment: He says it's hugely different, because its focus is on translatability: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=cbM4DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=basic%20english&f=false . But it's defined as "a common auxiliary inter-language for speakers of different languages, and as a global means for clarifying, elucidating, storing and comparing ideas." (p. 2) It's a minimal English-based auxlang, of which Basic English is the exemplar.

Comment: And they concede that Basic English is the comparison readers will first think so. But no, @curiousdannii, they do not explicitly say "we are reinventing Basic English."

Comment: Ah, that's what I suspected: regarding the poor editing and sloppy choice of semantic useful words. Thanks for the detailed answer!